# NPM Install Error (Package.JSON) not updating

Tags: node.js, bash, mongodb, package.json

In my terminal, lets say I am putting
npm install express mongoose bcrypt-nodejs morgan body-parser

I get this error.

> bson@0.2.19 install /Users/dan/nodeStuff/server-test/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

What's driving me crazy is that my node_moduales get updated in my directory but what doesn't get updated is the package.json file. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `--save` flag

```
npm install express mongoose bcrypt-nodejs morgan body-parser --save
```

Comment: I've tried that @jordan and I get the same situation. Node_modules are built with the dependency folders but without the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

By default `npm install` does not update the package.json. You can tell it to by passing `--save`, `--save-exact`, etc:

`$ npm install --save-exact express`

Details are in the [npm install documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Comment: I followed the documentation and your terminal command on a dummy test directory. I am under the impression that the package.json file is supposed to be in the root and not within the module folders itself. I see a package.json file in the express folder.

Comment: You have to create a package.json in your root directory first. You can do this using the `npm init` command.

Comment: Thank you @thereddest I thought that npm install would automatically input and create the package.json file for me.

Answer (score 0):

use `$npm init` to initialise package.json file. It formats this file in a certain way, that npm can update. Don't change the formatting of this file yourself or with any text editor like Visual Studio.
This way `$npm install` with `--save` option should update package.json file.